# PHP saving data for logged in users

Tags: php, mysql

I'm quite new to PHP and would appreciate a piece of advice on storing data. I managed to create a fully functioning log in script that takes a registered user to their "members area".

Next, I would like the user to be able to create their own content and save it. That content would then be accessible through their members area.

This would not be an issue for me if there was only one user, but how can I make this work for more different users?

EDIT: I'm not asking for code or any deep insight, I'd just like to know a general way of dealing with this.

Comment: It is a very big thing that you are asking! Maybe you should start reading about relational databases and then session variables in PHP. Good luck!

Comment: Why would this be any different for multiple users instead of just one user? If you think that it would be, then you're probably doing it wrong for one user.

Comment: Using [**sessions**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) will prove to be beneficial. Use the person's ID and assign a variable to it. I.e.: `$id=$_SESSION['id'];` --- Then, just fetch through (echo) your columns (*and/or* write content) if the session is set.

Comment: Session data is user-specific. In other words - if a session ID exists then that means the user is logged in (if Ondra implemented his login this way), but other users would not be able any data stored in this user's session, and if the session were lost (like, if the server decided that the session has timed out), then the data would be gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the user "to be able to create their own content and save it", presumably for other users to see. That means you need to store the content. A database usually makes the most sense for this.

General approach would be: when your user saves his own content, you would commit it to the database. Then when another user wants to see your user's content (perhaps by going to a profile page with your user's ID in the URL), you would then query that content from the database.

A good PHP model-view-controller framework will give you the ability to manipulate database data as PHP objects. There are several such frameworks available; give one a try!

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a vague question. Not going to go into details since you're asking for a general way, but here are some pointers

- After user logs in, save their username (and whatever else) in a session
- Create a page where they can enter content. In this page, you would check if $_SESSION['username'] is set. If not, redirect them to the login page
- Once they enter their content (ie, a ), save that in a database of of some sort(ie,mysql).

Your most basic mysql table(for this example) would have two columns:

- id
- username
- content

**users table:**

```
    +----------+--------------+----------------+ 
    |   id     |   username   |   content      |
    +----------+--------------+----------------+
    |    1     |    ondra     | white pony!    |
    +----------+--------------+----------------+
```

Say you want to show the world what that user entered as content. You would have a page like
www.example.com/content.php

in content.php, you would fetch information for the username storred in the $_SESSION['username'] that you set after the user logged in,

```
select * from `users` where username = $_SESSION['username']
```

Since I'm logged in and there's a session holding my username, the query above would work.

Please note the above is super basic and insecure. just trying to show you the general direction.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the reply. I might not have explained my issue very clearly, but this seems to be pretty close.

Comment: I'm already using sessions and I'm already storing a username in a session. I did not point out that I want the content to be private - only the user who created it can see it and read it from a database.  I'm just very unclear on how do I link particular database tables/columns with particular users.

Comment: Each user has a unique username or ID in the database. So when I login, you store my username in a session ($_SESSION['username']). Then on the page you want to show me my information, you would "select * from `users` where username $_SESSION['username']"